# Office 2016 - Missing advanced connectivity options with Power Query

Tags: office365, powerquery, excel-2016

We have install Office 2016 as C2R (with an "Office 365 Enterprise E3" license), on different platforms like Windows 7 (x64) and Windows Server 2008 R2 (x64).

At installations with "Windows Server 2008 R2" and Windows 7 (on a FatClient) are a lot of connections from Power Query missing, like in this thread / picture:
https://superuser.com/questions/1062456/excel-2016-list-of-options-for-connection-to-db-has-suddenly-reduced-mysql-po

**BUT** on devices with Windows 7 (VM on Terminal Server) it looks like ->
Section: **Advanced connectivity options with Power Query** on ->
https://blogs.office.com/en-us/2015/09/18/new-ways-to-get-the-excel-business-analytics-features-you-need/ and all connections can be used!

On all platforms was install the same Click2Run package. Excel shows under Info "**Microsoft® Excel® 2016 MSO (16.0.8431.2110) 32-Bit**".

The extended connections are only available under the Professional version but this is already installed.

Under Office 2013, the Power Query add-in was manually installed, the error did not exist there.

Grateful for any help

Comment: Probably more an issue for Microsoft Support. It's not exactly a solution to the menu options not appearing, but have you tried using a query that utilizes the missing connections options? I've used a few "advanced" query options in versions of Excel where they don't show up, but they worked anyways.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your answer, yes you are right. If i try to refresh a document, that was create whit Excel 2013 and use a connection to Active Directory, this works though the button is not displayed in the excel menu.

Next i have uninstall the Click2Run setup and try too install an non Click2Run version of Office 2016 professional (16.0.4266.1003) on the same system and this version works great!
Then i have uninstall this version and have install the newest Click2Run version 16.0.9126.2072, with this it works too, looks like it was a bug in the old Click2Run version.

[Example screenshot for advanced connectivity options in Excel 2016.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/doi6Q.png)